# Windows 8 start screen does not do partial name matching for all apps

Tags: windows-8, gvim

When I bring up the Windows 8 start screen and start typing the name of an App, it will do a partial match, on most apps but not all apps.

For example, if I type "wor" it finds "Word 2013" and "Wordpad"

But if I type "gvi" it does not find "gvim".

I have to type the full name, "gvim", for it to find "gvim".

Anyone have any idea about what is going on?

(Also before anyone suggests this, in "Folder Options" I already have "Find partial matches" checked)

Comment: I have the same problem with "cmder" (which does not show up even for "cmde"). But it does show for full name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does gvim show up if you click All Apps?

If not, I would guess there is no shortcut to it on the Start screen. The reason it matches when you type the full name is because the .exe is in a folder referenced by your PATH variable. The same thing happens with certain Windows utilities (e.g. msinfo32, mmc).